# Getting cursor data on Angular 7 and Swift DDP client

Tags: meteor, cursor, angular7, swift4.2

I am using `Meteor` as a `backend` server and I have two types of `frontends`.

- Swift 4.2.
- Angular 7.

So I am using `DDP` clients for both of them and I am facing some issues for both of them. For Angular 7, I am using [DDP.js](https://github.com/mondora/ddp.js/) and for Swift 4.2 I am using [SwiftDDP](https://github.com/siegesmund/SwiftDDP).

I can use `methods` and can also `subscribe` form both of frontends but the issue that I am facing is that I am getting cursor data on subscription when I call from both sides.

Well I used used to call the `collection` after `subscription` when I used `Angular2-Meteor` before and it was working fine but by using `DDP`, I can't call the `subscription`.

I have searched for it but didn't get any suitable solution for my problem.

I am calling a subscription from `Angular` by this method.

```
const subId = ddp.sub("products");
  ddp.on("ready", message => {
    if (message.subs.includes(subId)) {
      console.log("products ready");
    }
  });
  ddp.on("added", message => {
    console.log('message in added', message);
  });
```

I can get data on `added` in `message` but the data is in the `cursor` format, Is there anyway to get data in the `Array of Objects` format?

I am facing so many issues of this problem on `swift` client side, because swift is not reading the `cursor` format data.

Kindly guid me to convert this data into an `Array of Object` format.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: How exactly does swift not read the cursor format? Does it throw an error? If so, can you please add the error stack and the code snippet you used?

Comment: No, it is not throwing an error. 
Swift is reading cursor but when we use sorted on that cursor, we get an empty array.
And also application crashed because the fields didn't match to my pre-defined class, where both of them are same.

Comment: Can you use any of `find`, `forEach`, `map`, `fetch` or the [ES2015's iteration protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) ?

Comment: Can I use ES2015's iteration protocol in swift?

Comment: It just defines that something uses an iterator / is iterable. If the protocol is implemented on subscriptions in the SwiftDDP package then you could. At least I found some `forEach` in the [package code](https://github.com/siegesmund/SwiftDDP/blob/bc0858f8b3557eeba448821968cf6949e07dc096/Sources/DDPClient.swift#L214).

Comment: Ok, I try to sort it out with ES2015's iterations and I will let you know about it with further updates.

Comment: With using fetch, still gets the empty array.